# adding history reverse line number to a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following nice little bash function to make searches in my history (here for example, looking for ls commands):

```
history | grep --color=always ls | sort -k2 | uniq -f 1 | sort -n
```

I packaged it into a bash script, linked to an alias (*histg*) and it works great:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "-h" ]; then
  echo "A bash script to find patterns in history, avoiding duplicates (also non consecutive)"
  echo "expands to: XX"
  exit 0
fi

HISTSIZE=100000            # need this, because does not read .bashrc so does not know how big a HISTSIZE
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history   # Or wherever you bash history file lives
set -o history             # enable history

OUTPUT="$(history | grep --color=always $1 | sort -k2 | uniq -f 1 | sort -n)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

Typically, I get this kind of output:

```
$ histg SI
 16424  git commit -m "working on SI"
 16671  git commit -m "updated SI"
 17782  cd SI/
```

However I want to do one more improvement, and I do not know how to proceed. I want to be able to quickly call those commands again, but as you see I have a big hist, so typing `!17782` is a bit long. If the current size of my history is for example 17785 (I have a max history size 100000), I would like to see:

```
$ histg SI
 16424  -1361  git commit -m "working on SI"
 16671  -1114  git commit -m "updated SI"
 17782  -3     cd ~/Desktop/crrt/wrk/SI/
```

so that I can type in `-3`

Any idea how I can adapt my bash command to add this column?

Comment: Count the lines in your history (17785), iterate on each matched line, substract the line number (17782), negate it with `-` (-3), add this to the output?

Comment: Something like that. I know how to get number of lines in history (history | wc -l), but then start the hard work. How can I insert in a reliable way (with space paddings) the result of the calculation (field_1 - wc_value)?

Comment: You can pad with `printf "%10s" "$string"` for example. `man 3 printf`

Comment: what about using `tac` (the inverse of `cat`) and add line, and an additional `tac`. (not so efficient, but simple)

Comment: I am not sure how this would look like. Do you have a ```tac``` example for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a first try, my code was not working as expected because the negative numbers didn't match: the current session history was not taken into account. So I changed your script to a function (to add to `.bashrc`). The tricky part is handled by `awk`:

```
function histg() {
    history | grep --color=always $1 | sort -k2 | uniq -f 1 | sort -n \
    | awk '
    BEGIN { hist_size = '$(history|wc -l)' }
    {
        n = $1; $1 = ""
        printf("%-7i %-7i %s\n", n, n - hist_size, $0)
    }'
    history -d $(history 1)
}
```

The last line deletes the call to `histg` in history, so the negative numbers still keep sense.